# Troubleshoot of beforeunload confirm call

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

My Code:

```
//hold window open on form change
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if(formChanges > 0) {
        if(formData != initFormData) {
            if(confirm('here')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                e = null;
            }
        }
        else {
            e = null;
        }
    }
    else {
        e = null;
    }
};
```

The three vars (`formChanges`, `formData`, and `initFormData`) are all being filled correctly, and little tests have shown that they are being read correctly within the function. The problem is that the page unloads nomatter what, and no confirmation dialog ever appears.

The console log flashes for a moment before being unloaded (I can't seem to write it's contents to file) and I can see the message `Blocked confirm 'here' during beforeunload`, but it's gone before I can access it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a modal dialog before beforeunload shows its own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221121/how-to-show-a-modal-dialog-before-beforeunload-shows-its-own)

Comment: This is old, but a tip for people debugging.  In the console (at least in Google Chrome) under settings check `Preserve log` this will keep the "flashed" errors so you can see them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WHen using onbeforeunload you have to return a string, like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Does this mean I cannot run `if else` statements within the function?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it can only return a string, and is not cross-browser anyway. Thanks!